# саппортает ли спринг Rest + Websockets в одном приложении?

Tags: java, spring, rest, websocket

Пишу приложение. основная часть будет на вебсокетах.Но судя по гайдам в интернете, некоторые части должны быть не через вебсокеты, например авторизация. Столкнулся с проблемой что при описании вебсокет конфига для спринга отваливаются обычные контроллеры.

```
@RestController
public class FieldController
{
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getString", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getString()
    {
        return "[{\"id\":11, \"name\":\"qwer\"}]";
    }
}
```

контроллер сам по себе работает и возвращает строку.
но если я добавляю в приложение класс конфиг для вебсокетов

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer
{

    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addEndpoint("/socket").withSockJS();
    }

    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/qwer")
        .enableSimpleBroker("/asdf");
    }
}
```

то контроллер выше перестает возвращать значение. в логе

org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
   WARNING: No mapping for GET app/getString

ощущение что я что-то теряю и все должно работать, в интернете и в доках спринга ничего про это нету. если приложение писать на жава вебсокетах(не через спринг) то все работает. Помогите видит ли кто почему не работает?

Comment: конечно. сам делал такое. Надо наконфигурить правильно. Вам прямо говорят что маппинга `app/getString` нет, а в коде я вижу `@RequestMapping(value = "/getString")`. Проверьте это.

Comment: @Tsyklop как его может не быть если я по этому урлу захожу когда вебконфиг класса нету
http://localhost:8080/app/getString вот так без класса работает. так же когда я просто добавляю вебсокетконфиг класс уже не работает, хотя я даже вебсокет контроллеров не добавлял

Comment: И зачем ему надо маппинг app делать?